# Regex: Get a list of keywords between string literals

Tags: regex

I have a candidate string:

```
{{keywords: "blah blah", "blah, blah blah", "blah, blah some other text"}}
```

Using a regular expression, how would I get the list of the quoted keywords?

Update:

So I'm trying to accomplish this using pure PCRE, and unless someone can come up with a single expression, I'm going to have to break it into two processes:

1. Check if the complete piece of text contains a keywords line:

   `{{keywords[ ]*([^}]+)}}`
2. Break the resultant comma-delimited quoted text into pieces:

   `"([^"]+)"+`

Comment: **[What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)**

Comment: Sorry, I should have added I need to make sure the matching starts only after {{keywords:

Comment: I've tried using the following:

{{keywords: ("[^"]*")+

but it only matches the first quoted string

Comment: A) what is wrong with doing this in two steps?
B) what is wrong with using a classic LL(1) parser? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
/\{\{keywords: "([^"]+)"/gc
```

using Perl conventions. You know, the correct syntax depends very much on the language you are using, so if you could be more specific about that, it would help. In Perl you could what you need in two steps:

```
string =~ /\{\{keywords: /c;
```

this (due to the `c` modifier) would have the effect of moving the regex pointer to after `{{keywords:`; then you would do:

```
/"([^"]+)"/gc
```